# Multiple .gitignore in subfolders

Tags: git, gitignore, subdirectory

Is it possible to have a .gitignore file in a subfolder, so that i may be better able to control what i need to be ignored and not affect a larger, "base" gitignore?

For example, there is the root .gitignore, but instead of lets say writing /path/to/folder in that file, in my folder to have another .gitignore that will only apply for that folder and it's children?

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: @alfunx oh right, my bad. I had actually tried it but i wanted to ignore modified files, but when i created a new file it ignored it.

Answer (score 44):

Answer is: Yes, it is possible to have a `.gitignore` file in a subfolder.

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> When deciding whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks `gitignore` patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome):
>
> - Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support them.
> - Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, **or in any parent directory**, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file. A project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.
> - [...]

Thanks alfunx

Comment: @DevJoe The question was a Yes or No. I've expanded the answer with the documentation.

Comment: How do you negate from the __subfolder's__ `gitignore` i.e. in __root__ `gitignore` have `subfolder/` & `!subfolder/.gitignore` then in __subfolder__'s `gitignore` have `!file.json` or `!subSubFolder/*.js`

Comment: @user14492 I wouldn't do it that way. Instead, *don't* ignore the subfolder in file `root/.gitignore`; no need to mention it at all. Then, in file `root/subfolder/.gitignore`, either (a) ignore those files and directories that need ignoring, or, (b) ignore everything, and then unignore those files and directories that you want to include in your repository (lines `!filename`).