# Can a gitignore file have a name?

Tags: git, gitignore

For example, can you name a `.gitignore` file `foo.gitignore`?

Ultimately, the purpose for this being to have multiple `.gitignore` files for different sub-project types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple .gitignore in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208235/multiple-gitignore-in-subfolders)

Comment: @GeekyQuentin not really. That's more for putting .gitignore files at multiple diffrent subdirectories. I was wondering if it was possible to have multiple gitignore files in the same directory, differentiating them through filenames. Although I do understand that it's probably better to just separate them into subdirectories.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your need. Would having a set of `.gitignore` file templates somewhere and copying the right one to each new repo fit your need ?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, not natively.

I [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005830/6309) a content-filter driver which, on checkout, would automatically modify a `.gitignore` with the content of other files (like a `foo.gitignore`).

However, that require a local setting to activate that driver

```
git config filter.gitignore.smudge 'script_to_modify_gitignore'
```

Meaning: when you clone the repository, that mechanism would not be immediately active, not without the manual `git config` step.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't.  Well, more precisely, it can have ***a*** name, but that name is always `.gitignore`.

(Note that you can store entries in `.git/info/exclude` as well, but that is never a tracked file and does not get committed.)